# Adding a flag for homework problems

Tags: feature-request, flagging, homework

I've noticed quite a few homework problems being posted on EE.SE which makes sense since the semester is just beginning.

Its known that these are off-topic, as in we just don't answer them.  I'm curious if we could get a flag specifically for homework questions.  Currently there doesn't seem to be a very suitable flag.

If I'm mistaken on there not being a suitable flag, let me know, but quite frankly I'm not sure which one to do.

Comment: Don't downvote because you disagree.  Downvote if the question is badly done.   It's still a good question, and if it were removed, someone else would ask the same thing.  (IMHO...I mean, I would :) )

Comment: @gbarry for a feature request [voting on meta sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/how-does-meta-stack-exchange-work/47635#47635) is different and is the correct way to disagree. That's also why you don't gain / lose reputation on meta posts and there's no automatic question bans.

Comment: Actually, StackOverflow used to have a [homework tag that is now officially deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated). The linked Meta question has links to a lengthy discussion and conclusions explaining why creating the tag was a bad idea. Since they've been there, done that, I see no reason for us to repeat the same mistake.

Comment: Putting my money where my mouth is on http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/152369/analyzing-op-amp-circuit -- I keep editing it to make the question history make sense  - and the accepted answer no longer answers the question.

Answer (score 17):

I don't think Homework is off-topic.  "Gimme the answer" is off topic, but a well-reasoned question, showing real effort in advance and reference to where the student is stuck is very welcome.

The response should not be "here's the answer", but a socratic shove in the right direction that encourages them to learn the concepts involved.

The right way certainly takes longer for the responder than the wrong way -- and that might be why even good HW problems may take a while to attract a good answer.

Comment: Your approach to "guiding" toward the answer is noble, but utimately some show-off shows up and gives the answer.

Comment: @gbarry: Yes, that's why we all need to downvote answers that just do the homework for you.

Answer (score 11):

My strategy for homework questions.

1. If the O.P. has demonstrated effort for solving the problem and he is genuinely stuck, then homeworkness of the question is not a problem.  (There may be other issues, though.)
2. If the O.P. have not demonstrated effort, I post a comment asking
   "*What have you tried so far?*"
   Maybe the O.P. is new to EE.SE and he doesn't know that he has to show his attempts.
3. If the O.P. doesn't post his attempts, I close-vote with a custom message "*Homework, initial effort not demonstrated.*"