# Closing homework questions with an attempt

Tags: discussion

Its homework time, seeing as how most universities are approaching finals week. As of late I've seen a few questions that are homework [with an attempt](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/299127/operating-region-for-nmos-transistor-can-someone-check-my-work) in the VTC bin. Historically we have talked about [closing homework with no attempt as off topic](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5667/closing-homework-with-no-attempt-as-off-topic) but what do you do about homework with an attempt?

I think that these type of questions are fine as long as people put some kind of effort into solving them.

Comment: The issue with homework questions is real .In ye good olde bad olde days you had to get 50% in the Final Exam to pass so if you helped students you were not in any way facilitating cheating .Now with the  interm assessment it is feasable that someone could get a degree by getting help from various stack exchanges ,Forums etc .I think it is now unfortunately safest to avoid helping with homework questions to avoid being accused of Academic Dishonesty.This is really negative stuff .Would it be better for all colleges to make people have to get 50% in the final so then anybody can help anybody.

Comment: @Autistic it almost reads as if you want to protect yourself from academic dishonesty when avoiding answering homework questions.  Only the person who is asking the question is liable even if they explicitly state that they are asking for exam answers there is no way to assume they are for real. Academic dishonesty is reserved for those in Academia.  The chemistry SE has the same issues and are keen to try and eliminate the stigma and inaccuracy it causes.  A good question with a good answer is good for SE, the option of waiting to answer for a while if they appear to be homework is possible.

Comment: When I read this, my first thought was "what about people trying putting up any old answer or attempt in order to get round the rules?". Is that's [what's happening now](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/301591/output-voltage-at-load-resistor-given-figure)? Do we need to qualify the rule to stop a "straw man" approach?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure we need a fixed policy.  You recognize bad questions when you see them.  You recognize lack of effort when you see it.

The question you first link to is simply a bad question, homework or not.  "Can you check my work?"  Is not a valid question.  If the poster took the time to explain what he was confused about, where his doubts of his work were, and what concepts he was having trouble with, that would make it a very good question, instead of a fairly bad question -- whether it was homework or not.

Rubber Duck explanations are the posters' friends.

Comment: Good Idea Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I just looked at the first question you linked to.  I don't see any work, just a bunch of stats for the transistors that appear to be copied directly from the problem statement.

I have added my close vote.

Comment: No, you've scanned the question. The question was to find the operating region of the MOS and the OP provided that information and wanted to double check. Could you say something about a policy on double checking (and answer the question here)? I could dig up more examples if you'd like.

Comment: @lap: I still don't see anything other than obvious subtracting of voltages already listed in the schematic.