# Which flag to use for no attempt on homework question?

Tags: support, feature-request, flagging

I saw several question about homework with absolutely no proof of attempt these days. I wonder if these question deserve a flag? If yes, which one? None of the actual flag fit for this need.

As said WesleyLee in the comment section of [this post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/307028/116604),

> At first looks like "low quality", but this question would be
>   salvageable if OP edits his attempts in. And "in need of moderator
>   intervention" seems a bit too dramatic. I really don't know

Comment: [Adding a flag for homework problems.](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5120/7036)  This question has come up before.

Comment: Just vote to close for the nearest handy reason.  We don't owe lazy students long explanations.  Actually, we already provide the explanation, just that they were too lazy to read it or too arrogant to care.  If you feel like going out of your way, you can chose the *off topic* close reason, then *other*, and write your own comment.  I usually write something like "We are not here to do your homework for you".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a flag for homework problems](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5112/adding-a-flag-for-homework-problems)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's only an issue for users with rep < 3,000. I can see that your rep is currently some 1,000 and that's probably why you're asking yourself about this. I had this very same doubt until I got beyond the 3,000 rep mark.

That's what I did then and what I do now:

1. When I had rep < 3,000 I just downvoted the question and hoped that a higher rep user saw that as a signal and closed the question himself. There are a lot of users with rep > 3,000 in EE.SE, and they pull they trigger fairly quick when a bad homework question comes in. Sometimes I also flagged it as "unclear what you're asking".
2. Now that I have rep > 3,000 I can add off-topic reasons (which also automatically adds a comment to the question, very convenient), an option unavailable if you're below that mark. See the screenshot below. That's what I use for this kind of questions when I'm the first user voting to close. Other users prefer to vote to close as "unclear what you're asking", and sometimes I use that option if the question already has 3-4 closing votes, just to avoid messing up too much.

[image]

However, all of these are just guidelines, personal preferences or unwritten rules at best. I would also like to see a dedicated "homework attempt with no solution attempt" off-topic flag. It would be a convenient feature for users under 3,000 rep, and would also send a clearer message to users incurring in this kind of off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, we just leave a comment about "homework with no attempt at a solution" and vote to close as "unclear what you're asking".

There's really no need for moderator intervention.